# Change menu on screen size does work for div but not for a

Tags: html, css, media

I'm working on a responsive menu.

I have build my menu like this:

HTML:

```
<ul id="top-menu">
 <li class="active">
  <a href="#">HOME</a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="#div2">ABOUT</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#top-menu {
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
background:#000;
width:100%;
height:60px;
list-style:none;
z-index:100;
margin:0 0 0 0;
}

#top-menu a {
display:block;
width:100px;
text-align:center;
line-height:60px;
text-decoration:none;
height:60px;
color:#FFF; 
}
```

This all works fine. Now I try to make a responsive menu. I decided to try some stuff since I'm new to this. And I came across something which made me wonder why it didnt work.

For some reason this does work: (hides the menu)

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    #top-menu    {
       display: none;
    }
}
```

And this doenst: (nothing happens)

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    #top-menu a{
       display: none;
    }
}
```

I have googled and stuff but dont really get an answare? I assume it is possible to change an "A" or?

Hope anyone can help me out.

Greetings merijn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand...

having this `#top-menu a` to `display none` is correct - hides the lis

while the #menu hides all

http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/9kwwX/

Comment: Well.. really wierd. Its not working overhere.. Usin chrome. #top-menu is working fine.. but when I add A to it like #top-menu a its stops working..

Comment: If it works for me then you have either something not closed properly. check Chrome console bug or Firebug

Comment: yeah you're right. Well I have tried to edit the li (#top-menu li) this also works fine. Guess I'm gonna use that. Anyway quite wierd. If I find out what the problem is ill let you know! thanx

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the css rule with something like this?

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .active a{
       display: none;
    }
}
```